# How to determine size of text drawn in rectangle

Tags: vb.net

I am outputting text on a printed page and using drawstring to draw the text in a rectangle so that it will word wrap using a call such as:

```
 ev.Graphics.DrawString(textToOutput, printFont, myBrush, New RectangleF(leftMargin, yPosition, pagewidth - leftMargin - rightmargin, 400))
```

This works fine. What I am trying to determine is what the Y position would be after the drawscreen call (in other words, what was the height of the text after it was wrapped in the rectangle). I am trying to print variable length strings from a database and they will frequently exceed the page width. I need to know where the vertical start of the next paragraph will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx) and perhaps [this overload of it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58.aspx). Part of the example from MSDN:

```
Dim stringSize As New SizeF
stringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(measureString, stringFont, stringWidth)
```

Your calculated height would be stored in [SizeF.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.sizef.height%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).